# Writing API for Calling Python Script

Tags: python, api, ansible

I 've written playbook for specific deployment on kubernetes cluster, I 've placed that playbook in a remote linux server.
I want to integrate that playbook with a website form hosted on different domain. When a user fill that form that ansible-playbook should be triggered.
I need to setup an API for this, can anyone help on this.
API to launch python script which will call specific ansible playbook.

Answer (score 0):

Im using this python code to call a playbook :

```
import subprocess
myplaybook = subprocess.Popen(["ansible-playbook", "path/to/myplaybook.yaml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = myplaybook.communicate()  #to get output
print(out, err)
```

And if you have a playbook with varibels use like this:

```
myvar = "myvar=123"
myplaybook = subprocess.Popen(["ansible-playbook","-e",myvar, "path/to/myplaybook.yaml"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```